# Refactoring class component around Pusher

Tags: reactjs, pusher

I'm usually ok at this. Maybe my brain is a bit fried and I need to walk away from screen for a bit..

Can someone help me refactor the below into a functional component, for my sanity..

I'm struggling moving around the code to get with of componenetwillmount and ideally wanted to replace axios with fetch with useeffect (so it is similar to rest of my code)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
import axios from 'axios';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import CustomGridItem from '../components/Grid/CustomGridItem'
import CardHeader from '@material-ui/core/CardHeader';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import moment from 'moment';

    class App extends Component {
      state = {
        username: '',
        date: '',
        color: "#ffff80",
        newComment: '',
        comments: [],
      };

      updateInput = event => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        this.setState({
          [name]: value,
        });
      };

      postComment = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const { username, newComment, color } = this.state;
        if (username.trim() === '' || newComment.trim() === '') return;

        const data = {
          name: username,
          text: newComment,
          color: color,
          date: moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY h:mm:ss a'),
        };

        axios
          .post('http://localhost:1234/comment', data)
          .then(() => {
            this.setState({
              username: '',
              newComment: '',
              color: '',
              date: moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY h:mm:ss a')
            });
          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
      };

      componentDidMount() {
        const pusher = new Pusher('xxxxxxxxxx', {
          cluster: 'eu',
          encrypted: true,
        });

        axios.get('http://localhost:1234').then(({ data }) => {
          this.setState({
            comments: [...data],
          });
        }).catch(error => console.log(error))

        const channel = pusher.subscribe('comments');
        channel.bind('new-comment', data => {
          this.setState(prevState => {
            const { comments } = prevState;
            comments.push(data.comment);

            return {
              comments,
            };
          });
        });
      }

      render() {
        const { username, newComment, date, color, comments } = this.state;
        const { classes } = this.props;
        const userComments = comments.map(e => (
          <CustomGridItem color={e.color} xs={12} md={12} lg={12} xl={12} key={e._id}>
            <CardHeader title={e.name} subheader={e.date} />
            <CardContent>{e.text}</CardContent>
          </CustomGridItem>
        ));

        return (
          <div className="App">
            <Grid container direction="row" justify="flex-start" alignItems="stretch" spacing={3} >
            {userComments}
            </Grid>
            <br /> <br />
            <section className="comments-form">
              <form onSubmit={this.postComment}>
                <label htmlFor="username">Name:</label><br />
                <input
                  className="username"
                  name="username"
                  id="username"
                  type="name"
                  value={username}
                  onChange={this.updateInput}
                />
                <input
                  className="date"
                  name="date"
                  id="date"
                  type="hidden"
                  value={date}
                />
                <br />
                <label htmlFor="new-comment">Comment:</label><br />
                <textarea
                  name="newComment"
                  id="new-comment"
                  value={newComment}
                  onChange={this.updateInput}
                /><br />
                <label htmlFor="new-comment">Note colour:</label><br />
                <input
                  type="color"
                  name="color"
                  id="color"
                  value={color}
                  onChange={this.updateInput}></input><br /><br />
                <button type="submit">Add Note!</button>
              </form>
            </section>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

I should add, the below is what I tried...ive managed to pull the posts through now ok, but as soon as I click on a form element i get a "cannot read property of map.e of undefined (line 84) - updated after help from comment below :)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
import axios from 'axios';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import CustomGridItem from '../components/Grid/CustomGridItem'
import CardHeader from '@material-ui/core/CardHeader';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import moment from 'moment';

const App = (props) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
                                    username: '',
                                    date: '',
                                    color: '#ffff80',
                                    newComment: ''})

  const [comments, setComments] = useState([])

  const updateInput = event => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        setFormData({
          [name]: value,
        });
        console.log(username)
        console.log(newComment)
      };

  const postComment = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const { username, newComment, color } = formData;
        if (username.trim() === '' || newComment.trim() === '') return;

        const data = {
          name: username,
          text: newComment,
          color: color,
          date: moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY h:mm:ss a'),
        };

        axios
          .post('http://localhost:1234/comment', data)
          .then(() => {
            setFormData({
              username: '',
              newComment: '',
              color: '',
              date: moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY h:mm:ss a')
            });
          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
      };

      useEffect(() => {

        const fetchData = async () => {

        const pusher = new Pusher('xxxxxxxxxx', {
          cluster: 'eu',
          encrypted: true,
        });

        axios.get('http://localhost:1234').then(({ data }) => {
          setComments([...data]);
        }).catch(error => console.log(error))

        const channel = pusher.subscribe('comments');
        channel.bind('new-comment', data => {
          setComments(prevState => {
            const { comments } = prevState;
            comments.push(data.comment);

            return {
              comments,
            };
          });
        });

      }

      fetchData();

    }, []);



        const { username, newComment, date, color } = formData;
        const { classes } = props;
        const userComments = comments.map(e => (
          <CustomGridItem color={e.color} xs={10} md={10} lg={10} xl={10} key={e._id}>
            <CardHeader title={e.name} subheader={e.date} />
            <CardContent>{e.text}</CardContent>
          </CustomGridItem>
        ));

        return (
          <div className="App">
            <Grid container direction="row" justify="center" alignItems="stretch" spacing={3} >
            {userComments}
            </Grid>
            <br /> <br />
            <section className="comments-form">
              <form onSubmit={postComment}>
                <label htmlFor="username">Name:</label><br />
                <input
                  className="username"
                  name="username"
                  id="username"
                  type="name"
                  value={username}
                  onChange={updateInput}
                />
                <input
                  className="date"
                  name="date"
                  id="date"
                  type="hidden"
                  value={date}
                />
                <br />
                <label htmlFor="new-comment">Comment:</label><br />
                <textarea
                  name="newComment"
                  id="new-comment"
                  value={newComment}
                  onChange={updateInput}
                /><br />
                <label htmlFor="new-comment">Note colour:</label><br />
                <input
                  type="color"
                  name="color"
                  id="color"
                  value={color}
                  onChange={updateInput}></input><br /><br />
                <button type="submit">Add Note!</button>
              </form>
            </section>
          </div>
        );

    }

    export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `axios.post(...).then(...)` calls `setState` without `comments`. setter for `useState` does not merge object as it happens in class components but replace value completely.

So after clicking button -> running `postComment` you are ending up with

```
.then(() => {
  setState({
    username: "",
    newComment: "",
    color: "",
    date: moment().format("MMMM Do YYYY h:mm:ss a")
});
```

And sure, after re-render your `comments` is `undefined`.

The easiest way to handle that is splitting state into several independent variables like

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
  username: '',
  date: '',
  color: "#ffff80",
  newComment: ''
});
const [allComments, setAllComments] = useState([]);
```

So they will not interfere with each other.

Comment: thanks, that seems to have helped - ive just hit one other problem, when go to submit, I get a new error message, cannot read property "trim" of undefined. I've put a console.log in the updateInput function and it seems when i type in the username box, it makes the newcomment box undefined and visa versa...

Comment: the same. split into 2 separate data+setter pairs.